# Errors when refreshing migration of DB tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, database-migration

After refreshing my migrations im getting issues between users migrations and account Types users table, cant figure out the problem.

**Error**

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'account_typ
  es' already exists (SQL: create table `account_types` (`id` int unsigned no
  t null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(50) not null, `created_at
  ` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb
  4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'account_typ
  es' already exists
```

My Migrations

**Account Types**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('account_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('account_types');
    }
```

**Users**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname', 20);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('mobilephone', 9);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

Relation ship between the users and account types, i believe that maybe the problem is here, but still cant figure out what is wrong with the migration code.

**Relation of Users and Account Types**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->integer('account_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('account_type_id')
                ->references('id')->on('account_types');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('users_account_type_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('account_type_id');
        });
    }
```

Comment: How you checked out in what order your migrations are running. Running `php artisan migrate:rollback` will start at the bottom of you `migrations` table and work it's way back up

Answer (score 0):

Like I had many times before there occurred an error when you were migrating and you get this error because the migration script hasn't had the chance to register the last migration.

If you don't care about the data already stored drop all the tables in your database manually (even the migrations table) and rerun.

When you have data in your tables you want to keep you should check this migrations table and look at the batch column. Put every entry on 1 you want to keep and set the row and the rows below it on 0 (maybe deleting them will also work). Run `php artisan migrate`. When using phpmyadmin you can update these rows by query, eg: `UPDATE migrations SET batch=0 WHERE migration LIKE "%create_users_table";`

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

first remove **account_types**, **users** from migrations table in your database.

And refresh your migrations.

Hope this works for you!